# Mingw -mconsole option causes linkage error on undefined referces for MS GUI functions

Tags: c, mingw, windows-console

I was told several times, that `-mwindows` and `-mconsole` command line switches of mingw actually effects only a single bit in the EXE header or so, and not too much other. However this does not seem to be true. If I try using `-mconsole` in a project of mine, I get the following error at linkage:

```
../../build/objs/t-win32-ep128-xep128--gui.o:gui.c:(.text+0xb3): undefined reference to `_imp__GetOpenFileNameA@4'
../../build/objs/t-win32-ep128-xep128--gui.o:gui.c:(.text+0xc7): undefined reference to `_imp__CommDlgExtendedError@0'
```

OK, I think, the problem that GUI-related options cannot be used with -mconsole. However then it's a trap for me, since I need to write an application which uses the functions like `GetOpenFileName()` but still it needs the console since I write debug messages there with `printf()` and such. Also it seems to be in conflict with the "common knowledge" opinion that `-mconsole` / `-mwindows` switches only affects a single EXE header element, so Windows will know to allocate console or not for the application. Yes, I could allocate a console myself, but it's ugly, since I would like to use the console the program started from. What can be the solution in this case? Thanks.

Comment: You're doing wrong something else. I have a well-working console program here creating a window and all sorts of controls, and running a message loop.

Comment: @eryksun and because this requires the user to do something unusual, it's messy. Alternative, if you need a "hybrid" app: Stick with `console` subsystem and if started e.g. without command line arguments, "detach" yourself (`CreateProcess()` your own executable with `DETACHED_PROCESS`). This only has the "console window flash" problem ;)

Comment: Actually, the linkage is fine if there is -mwindows option. If I change it to -mconsole, I got the problem with undefined references! I've tried to include -luser32 too, but no difference.

Comment: @LGBGáborLénárt did you add `-luser32` **after** your input files?

Comment: @FelixPalmen: I know, ld can be a bit picky about the order, so I've tried that too (also at the very end of the command line, etc), but all of them have the very same result, I've demonstrated in my question post.

Comment: I'm just thinking that my ideas may be not so well suited for Windows ... Basically what I want to get, is the same behaviour as would be with UNIX systems. Ie, I have an application using (let's say) GTK+ GUI, it's fine. I can still use printf() just nobody will see it. But if user starts the app from a terminal window, then the stdout/stderr can be seen (or if redirected to a file, for example) but surely, GUI still works. However I cannot understand this unneeded complexity of Windows thinking on the Console :-( Maybe it cannot be even done in Windows this way? Sorry about the mess then ...

Comment: @LGBGáborLénárt it can be done, with quirks, as I outlined in a comment above. But you have to use some more "trickery" like creating a program shortcut that passes a `-gui` option (or similar), so your program knows it must "detach".

Comment: @LGBGáborLénárt and there's *definitely* something else wrong, as I said, it's no problem at all to have a *console* windows app use all the *GUI* stuff. Did you try to separate compilation and linking in individual steps, so you have better control in which order the objects / libraries are passed to the linker?

Comment: That something is broken in the build on your system doesn't mean it can't be done. Being a console application only changes the startup behavior regarding inheriting the parent's console and implicitly inheriting the standard handles. Console applications aren't confined to the console API. At the first call to a user32 function, Windows creates a `Win32Thread` structure for a thread, which supports a message queue and whatever else is required to operate within a graphical Desktop environment. It would work even with late binding via `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress`.

Comment: @FelixPalmen: Yes, separated. Compilation and linking are two distinct steps, at linking, I only refer to object files. Oooooo .... I have a bad feeling ... I use -mconsole or -mwindows only at the linking phase, not before, should I use at compilation too? Then my bad and sorry :-(

Comment: @LGBGáborLénárt no, they are only relevant at compile time. You don't need to use a switch at all for a console program.

Comment: Using the ANSI API for file-system related functions is going to be a problem in general. Unix programmers are of the mindset that filenames are just bytes, but in Windows they're Unicode text, and the user may select or enter a filename that doesn't encode correctly using the ANSI codepage. The encoding it uses is lossy -- mapping to approximately matching characters or a default character such as a question mark, which is an invalid file system character. It's better to use the wide-character UTF-16 API and transcode internally to UTF-8 if the rest of your program needs byte strings.

Comment: @eryksun "*Unix programmers are of the mindset that filenames are just bytes, but in Windows they're Unicode text*" -- they're Unicode as well on modern Unix systems, just using the more sane UTF-8 format ;) Otherwise, agreed with your comment. -- `WideCharToMultiByte()` and `MultiByteToWideChar()` with `CP_UTF8` works fine, using this in my own code.

Comment: @FelixPalmen, UTF-8 is the common locale encoding, but most Unix systems, modern or not, will accept *any* byte string in filenames, with the obvious exception that ASCII NUL and slash are special. I think OS X is one of the few that enforces valid UTF-8 in filenames.

Comment: @eryksun if that's what you mean, yes, nothing is actually *enforced*. But with a UTF-8 *locale*, you have to *actively* do strange stuff to get filenames that aren't valid UTF-8 :) (and that's this nice thing about UTF-8 ... in *nearly* any situation, you *can* think about it as "just bytes")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-mwindows` and `-mconsole` *really* only set a flag determining the type of windows application. If you don't specify any, it defaults to `console`.

That said, it might be that the default linking options differ in what libraries are automatically linked to. E.g. for `GetOpenFileName()`, you need to link to `comdlg32`. The following example works as expected:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    OPENFILENAMEA ofn = {sizeof(ofn)};
    char filename[1024] = {0};
    ofn.lpstrFile = filename;
    ofn.nMaxFile = 1024;

    GetOpenFileNameA(&ofn);

    printf("selected: %s\n", filename);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
$ gcc -oopendemo opendemo.c -lcomdlg32
$ ./opendemo.exe
selected: C:\temp\winsdksetup.exe
```

---

Examining the behavior of my mingw gcc, when linking without any libraries and without `-mwindows`, it adds the following libs:

> -lmingw32 -lgcc -lgcc_eh -lmoldname -lmingwex -lmsvcrt -lpthread -ladvapi32 -lshell32 -luser32 -lkernel32 -lmingw32 -lgcc -lgcc_eh -lmoldname -lmingwex -lmsvcrt

with `-mwindows`, the list looks as following:

> -lmingw32 -lgcc -lgcc_eh -lmoldname -lmingwex -lmsvcrt -lpthread -lgdi32 -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32 -lshell32 -luser32 -lkernel32 -lmingw32 -lgcc -lgcc_eh -lmoldname -lmingwex -lmsvcrt

So, indeed, `gdi32` and `comdlg32` are automatically added with `-mwindows`, probably because they are needed by *many* GUI programs.

Comment: Hmm, that works ... After I added -lcomdlg32. However it works with -mwindows even without adding -lcomdlg32. So maybe, as you've told, it can be also a hint what kind of stuffs should be linked or so when I use -mwindows besides it also alters something in the EXE header for signalling Windows being console/GUI app?

Comment: @LGBGáborLénárt I checked that, see my update. Just call `gcc` with the `-v` option to check yourself

Comment: It's an interesting and useful outcome (for me at least), I thought -mwindows/-mconsole only sets something in the EXE header. But it seems there is some other functionality as well. As far as I remember it was not mentioned in gcc's man page (okey, it's not so mingw specific, but gcc in general ...) it only says it's set something in the EXE header... Nice to know!

Comment: It *should* be documented somewhere. But then, linking the libraries you intend to use is what you normally do. Adding "standard windows gui" libraries with `-mwindows` seems reasonable, but unnecessary -- don't know why mingw decided to do so.

Comment: Indeed. It's may bad, that I am dumb for Windows (I develop for UNIX systems, just it's nice to have cross compilation of my work for Windows OS as well from time to time), so I couldn't even now, I would need `comdlg32` as it worked with `-mwindows` without the need of its "manual" specification. But at least I could learn something now :)